# Access SQL: Select TOP 1 record from each ResourceID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get 5 values with single SQL query from access database.

Each row has fields 'ID', 'ResourceID', 'TimeStamp' and other non-important values.

The field with the highest 'ID' is newest value, but same 'ResourceID' can be multiple times the newest 'ID'.

I tried a query like this, but this can return same ResourceID multiple times. I just want the newest values of every 'ResourceID'

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tblMachineReport WHERE ResourceID in (61,63,64,68,70) ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Any tips? :)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT mr.*
FROM tblMachineReport as mr
WHERE mr.id = (SELECT MAX(mr2.ID)
               FROM tblMachineReport as mr2
               WHERE mr2.ResourceID = mr.ResourceID
              ) AND
      mr.ResourceID in (61, 63, 64, 68, 70)
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: The data is somewhat sensitive so I cant really paste it here. I tried this. It wont give error, but cant get any data logged out :/